# Cisco IOS Forward / reverse name lookups

Tags: cisco, dns

I want to configure our Ciscos so they can do forward DNS resolution, but not reverse DNS resolution from the CLI.

```
R01(config)#ip domain-name domain.local
R01(config)#ip name-server 10.1.1.1
R01(config)#ip domain-lookup
```

That config makes the router do a forward lookup when we ping, and reverse lookup under show commands that return ip addresses.  When we do a "show user", the router does a reverse lookup for every one of the source ip addresses.  It looks like we get both forward and reverse lookups when we turn on "ip domain-lookup".  Is there a way to turn off reverse lookups and leave forward lookups on?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could add those hosts with the ip host command though if they are not in your DNS. Any specific reason for not adding reverse records?

Comment: @DanielDib, regarding whether it's possible... all you need is `no domain-lookup` under the vty...

Comment: @MikePennington Nice. Never seen that used under the VTY.

Comment: @DanielDib, DNS is controlled by another group and they refuse to keep reverse records updated correctly.  It's an issue in our company that nobody in IT management wants to address because the person who controls DNS has too many political connections in the company, and he is very vindictive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is there a way to turn off reverse lookups and leave forward lookups on?

### Summary:

Use `no domain-lookup` under `line vty 0 4`...

### Details:

You're right, the default behavior is to perform & cache a forward / reverse lookup for the addresses in show commands.  This config starts similar to yours...

#### Baseline behaviour: Forward / Reverse lookups

```
HotCoffee#clear host *
HotCoffee#sh runn | i ip domain|ip name|^ +domain|NTP
Time source is NTP, 06:10:42.327 CDT Tue Aug 13 2013
ip domain name pennington.net
ip name-server 172.16.1.5
 domain-name pennington.net
HotCoffee#
```

After clearing the host cache, there are no entries in it...

```
HotCoffee#show host
Load for five secs: 0%/0%; one minute: 1%; five minutes: 1%
Time source is NTP, 06:11:46.864 CDT Tue Aug 13 2013

Default domain is pennington.net
Name/address lookup uses domain service
Name servers are 172.16.1.5

Codes: UN - unknown, EX - expired, OK - OK, ?? - revalidate
       temp - temporary, perm - permanent
       NA - Not Applicable None - Not defined

Host                      Port  Flags      Age Type   Address(es)
HotCoffee#
```

Doing a `show user` or `ping` populates the host cache...

```
HotCoffee#sh user
    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
* 66 vty 0     cisco      idle                 00:00:00 tsunami.pennington.net

  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address

HotCoffee#ping flame
Translating "flame"...domain server (172.16.1.5)

Translating "flame"...domain server (172.16.1.5) [OK]

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 172.16.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
.!!!!
Success rate is 80 percent (4/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/2/4 ms
HotCoffee#
```

Now there are host entries for both the `ping` target and `show user`...

```
HotCoffee#sh hosts
Load for five secs: 1%/0%; one minute: 0%; five minutes: 0%
Time source is NTP, 06:16:32.811 CDT Tue Aug 13 2013

Default domain is pennington.net
Name/address lookup uses domain service
Name servers are 172.16.1.5

Codes: UN - unknown, EX - expired, OK - OK, ?? - revalidate
       temp - temporary, perm - permanent
       NA - Not Applicable None - Not defined

Host                      Port  Flags      Age Type   Address(es)
tsunami.pennington.net    None  (temp, OK)  0   IP    172.16.1.5
flame.pennington.net      None  (temp, OK)  0   IP    172.16.1.1
flame                     None  (temp, UN)  0  IPv6 
HotCoffee#
```

#### Solution: Only Forward lookups

Use *`no domain-lookup`* under the vty / console lines to restrict IOS behaviour to only forward lookups...

```
HotCoffee#conf t
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
HotCoffee(config)#line vty 0 4
HotCoffee(config-line)#no domain-lookup
HotCoffee(config-line)#end
HotCoffee#
```

First I clear the host cache for a clean test...

```
HotCoffee#clear host *
HotCoffee#
HotCoffee#
```

`show user` formerly performed a reverse-lookup on 172.16.1.5 as well as populating the host cache, but neither happens now...

```
HotCoffee#sh user
Load for five secs: 1%/0%; one minute: 0%; five minutes: 0%
Time source is NTP, 06:20:00.250 CDT Tue Aug 13 2013

    Line       User       Host(s)              Idle       Location
* 66 vty 0     cisco      idle                 00:00:00 172.16.1.5   <----

  Interface    User               Mode         Idle     Peer Address

HotCoffee#
HotCoffee#sh host
Load for five secs: 2%/0%; one minute: 0%; five minutes: 0%
Time source is NTP, 06:20:06.729 CDT Tue Aug 13 2013

Default domain is pennington.net
Name/address lookup uses domain service
Name servers are 172.16.1.5

Codes: UN - unknown, EX - expired, OK - OK, ?? - revalidate
       temp - temporary, perm - permanent
       NA - Not Applicable None - Not defined

Host                      Port  Flags      Age Type   Address(es)
                                                                    <----
HotCoffee#
```

Just to show that forward lookups still function...

```
HotCoffee#
HotCoffee#ping flame
Translating "flame"...domain server (172.16.1.5)

Translating "flame"...domain server (172.16.1.5) [OK]

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 172.16.1.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/1/4 ms
HotCoffee#
HotCoffee#
HotCoffee#
HotCoffee#sh hosts
Load for five secs: 0%/0%; one minute: 0%; five minutes: 0%
Time source is NTP, 06:25:43.237 CDT Tue Aug 13 2013

Default domain is pennington.net
Name/address lookup uses domain service
Name servers are 172.16.1.5

Codes: UN - unknown, EX - expired, OK - OK, ?? - revalidate
       temp - temporary, perm - permanent
       NA - Not Applicable None - Not defined

Host                      Port  Flags      Age Type   Address(es)
tsunami.pennington.net    None  (temp, OK)  0   IP    172.16.1.5
flame.pennington.net      None  (temp, OK)  0   IP    172.16.1.1
flame                     None  (temp, UN)  0  IPv6 
HotCoffee#
```